# How to turn off multilingual typing without deleting dictionaries or keyboards in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, keyboard, language, dictionary, internationalization

This wasn't a problem in iOS 9 or earlier. However, now iOS 10 has added a new feature such that one doesn't have to switch keyboards to type in another language, which *causes trouble*: now I have both English and French dictionaries and both keyboards, and for example, when I type "critique" in the English keyboard, a word existing in both dictionaries, iOS will then prompt the French suggestions (de, le, la etc.), even though I never mean to switch to French -- I just want to normally type "critique" as an English word, but of course iOS can't detect my intention.

Anyway, now I want things to go back to what they were in iOS 9 or earlier. And I have to keep both the dictionaries and the keyboards. Is it possible?

Comment: Try adding another keyboard but no dictionary for it.  I think I saw somewhere that more than two may leave English unbothered by the feature.

Comment: @TomGewecke well that doesn't seem to work for me.. anyway let's hope it'll be fixed in later versions.

Comment: I think I should have written WITH the dictionary.  I have multiple keyboards and dictionaries and the English keyboard seems to stick to English.

Comment: @TomGewecke I have Chinese, French and English keyboards. Each with its own dictionary, and even additional ones such as French-English or Chinese-English, English-Chinese.

Comment: the definitions dictionaries have nothing to do with autocorrect. no idea why people think that they are related.

Comment: @lensovet yeah. And it seems that the cross-language issue persists.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to turn this off. A bunch of my friends get hilarious autocorrects because of this.

Answer (score 2):

Leave feedback with Apple or they will never fix this. All they need is a way to turn it on and off.

One good way is to use the Apple Support iOS app and check if you’ve missed an easy step. If not and this is truly by design, they should get you a feedback link where you can request this change in functionality.

- [Apple Support by Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-support/id1130498044?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

So far the only workaround seems to be using another keyboard, for example, google's [gboard](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/gboard-the-google-keyboard/id1091700242) or microsoft's [swiftkey](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-swiftkey-keyboard/id911813648) — both are heavy on data-collection but if you do *not* enable *Allow full access* in settings they are still fairly usable.

For gboard make sure you disable *Multilingual typing* in settings. To quickly access gboard settings long-tap the cogwheel <kbd>⚙️</kbd> icon. Normal single tap on <kbd>⚙️</kbd> can be used to switch between installed languages.